# Conversion a hex string adding 0x30 to each byte

Tags: python, string, hex

I have spent some hours and I can't resolve this problem on my own:

I have a string with some hex bytes like '03FE5', and I have to get another string with the same hex number, but in each digit add 0x30 so:

- Add 0x30 to '0' and get 0x30
- Add 0x30 to '3' and get 0x33
- Add 0x30 to 'F' and get 0x3F
- Add 0x30 to 'E' and get 0x3E
- Add 0x30 to '5' and get 0x35

Finally get them to a string obtaining '03?>5' which are the ascii results.

I've tried several things but maybe this are the closest to the right one:

```
message='03FE5'
y=""
for x in message: 
    y+=str(hex(int(x,16)+48))[2:]
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Of course I did, maybe is to obvious, but I'm a little frustrated.

Comment: Have you looked into bitwise operators? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Comment: I have tried converting to int each hex byte, adding 48, reconverting to hex, deleting the 2 first characters...

Comment: It helps if you post (a part of) your code, so people can give you tips on how to continue.

Comment: I have try serveral things but maybe this is the most close to the good one: message='03FE5'
y=""
for x in message: 
    y+=str(hex(int(x,16)+48))[2:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the operations are no-ops, so just take advantage of that fact:

```
>>> chrmap = {'A': '\x3a', 'B': '\x3b', 'C': '\x3c', 'D': '\x3d', 'E': '\x3e', 'F': '\x3f'}
>>> ''.join(chrmap.get(c, c) for c in '03FE5')
'03?>5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `0x30` is only going to help with the digit nibbles; for the letter nibbles (`ABCDEF`), you'll want to add `ord("A") - 0x0a` (or `ord("a") - 0x0a`).

If you look at the ASCII correspondence values (e.g.: `for i in range(128): print(i, chr(i))`), you'll see that all the numbers start at `0x30` but that letters don't start immediately afterwards - uppercase starts at `0x41` and lowercase starts at `0x61`. You want to subtract `0x0a` because you don't want to double-count -- if someone gives you the nibble `0x0b` and you add `ord("A")`, you're not going to get `B`, you're going to get `L`.